# How to get blank lines to show in a verbbox environment?

Tags: verbatim

Minimum working example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{verbatimbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{verbbox}
Line 1

Line 3

Line 5
Line 6
Line 7
\end{verbbox}

\theverbbox

\end{document}
```

This outputs:

[image: LaTeX output, displaying Line 1 Line 3 Line 5 Line 6 Line 7 on separate lines, without blank lines in between]

It ignores the blank lines.  I'm wondering how we can get the blank lines to display.

**Question**: How to get blank lines to show in a verbbox environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that is a bug.  But a workaround is to use the optional argument to place a blank `\mbox{}` at the beginning of each line.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{verbatimbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{verbbox}[\mbox{}]
Line 1

Line 3

Line 5
Line 6
Line 7
\end{verbbox}

\theverbbox

\end{document}
```

[image]